# Looping through a list of images in JSP and calling a servlet to display each one in a table, but the final output displays same image

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am working on an assignment in which I have to provide a user login after which he will be directed to a page where he can upload images and all of his previous + new images will be displayed below in a table. So the structure of my application is like this...

(trimmed most of the code for clarity)

JSP file that allows upload and displays the image

```
<p>Please select an image file to upload(Max file size 1 MB)</p>

<%
    Integer userId = 0;
    userId = (Integer) session.getAttribute("userId");
%>
<%
    String errorMessage = (String) request.getAttribute("error");
    if (errorMessage != null) {
        out.print("<h4> " + errorMessage + "</h4>");
    }
%>
<form action="imageupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <br /> <input type="file" name="uploader" id="uploader" /> <br /> <br />
    <input type="submit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="button"
        value="clear" onClick="clear()" />


</form>
<br />
<h4>Uploaded Images</h4>
<br />
<table width="80%">
    <tr>
        <th>S No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>size</th>
        <th>Preview</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <%
        UserImagesDAOImplementation userImages = new UserImagesDAOImplementation();

        List<Image> images = (List<Image>) userImages.getUserImages(userId);

        for (Image image : images) {
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=image.getSn()%></td>
        <td><%=image.getImageName()%></td>
        <td><%=image.getSize()%></td>
        <td><% session.setAttribute("image",image.getImage() ); %><img src="toimage" height="100px" width="100px" /></td>
        <td><img src="img/edit.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/url.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
    %>
</table>
<br />
Total space used: <%= (userImages.getSizeUsage(userId)/1024) %> KB / 10 MB
```

the "toimage" servlet that returns the image

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    Byte[] image = (Byte[]) session.getAttribute("image");
    int len = image.length;
    byte[] imageData = new byte[len];

    for(int i=0; i < len; i++) {
        imageData[i] = image[i];
    }

    response.setContentType("image/jpg");
    response.getOutputStream().write(imageData);
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.getOutputStream().close();

}
```

My problem is that it displays the last image in the list in all the table rows and after uploading some other image it displays that new image in every row.

I am not very confident about my design for the site but this is the first time I am working with JSP. I decided to get the image list inside JSP as I will have to perform some more operations on it later on. I guess the problem is either in setting the session variable or the src servlet being called in the end. Whatever it is, can someone please explain the typical flow of events in this design.

Edit:
Putting a print statement inside the "toimage" servlet proves that it is being called just once. So how can I make the JSP loop to call the image src every time ??

Comment: As a side note: [**using scriplets in JSP is highly discouraged**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/814702)

Answer (score 2):

You use a single session attribute to store every image. So, at the end of the loop, this session attribute contains the last one.

You shouldn't use the session at all. Instead, you should pass the ID or name or whatever identifies the image as a URL parameter:

```
<img src="toimage?imageId=<%= image.getId() %>" height="100px" width="100px" />
```

And the servlet should use this parameter to now which image it must oad and send to the browser.

Also, learn the JSTL and the EL. Scriptlets sould not be used.

Comment: I was expecting that to render my image on every iteration and in the next loop just replace the image attribute value and send a new one to the servlet. I dont understand why does it process everything in the end. Oh and after this one, JSTL will be the first thing i learn. I understand now why shouldn't we use scriptlets.